# Does a Doctor exist that is able to encapsulate triaging differing specialities?

Tags: medications

My girlfriend has multiple health issues:

- ASD
- ADHD
- BPD
- Type 1 Diabetes
- Wolf Parkinsons Disease
- Non-alcoholic fatty liver disease
- fibromyalgia
- Perferatted Valve
- Reynauds Disease

The issue is each one comes with their own specialists and due to heart problems she is unable to receive medication to ease the others. Each specialist has their own silo and priority list, so those with more of a serious condition in that particular speciality goes to the top of the list.

Is there a consultant or Doctor who oversees the bigger picture and can re- prioritise treatments? For example, if one problem is interfering with or delaying treatment of another problem, is there a doctor who can sort it out for her and recommend the best course of action? If so, what is this doctor called?

I am from the UK, so any advice on who can deal with these is greatly appreciated. We have spoken to the GP and they just refer to the specialists and the specialists themselves can't comment on the other aliments as it isn't their speciality, so seems to be stuck in this cycle.

Comment: I edited your question to make it comply with site guidelines so it could be reopened. (It was closed for a while if you didn't notice.) It would be helpful if you would [edit] the question to say what country you're in.

Comment: *"Is there a consultant or Doctor who oversees the bigger picture and can re- prioritise treatments?"*. Surely that would be your family primary care physician (US) General Practitioner (Europe).

Comment: In my opinion, the newest edit to this question has made it very clear that this is a request for personal medical advice. As such, I have voted to re-close.

Comment: If the GP can't help then you can always hire a private practice physician who would be willing to take on the role. But I have to agree with @IanCampbell's assessment that you've made this a personal medical advice question.

Comment: I am in the UK too and 2nd the comment by @CareyGregory - GPs co-ordinate all required medical examinations alongside the specialists who they refer to. If a specialist suggests you see a different specialist for other complaints they contact your GP to co-ordinate that. They may also copy in the relevant specialist team. If they don't, again, talking to your GP will instigate other specialist help where needed. If you are not happy, you are free to obtain a second opinion from another GP in the same practice or elsewhere (even private if you wish). NHS specialist consultants team up with GPs.

Comment: Thank you all, I will look down the private route. I will admit I am unsure where the personal medical advice has come from? I was requesting if a role existed that coordinates decisions from different specialists and not personal medical advice. The edit to the question was context of what had been discussed and the reason for the question.